# Why does python use . instead of / for paths in import statements?

Tags: python, syntax, language-design

I'm not familiar with other languages, so I don't know if they do this (or similar) as well (and am curious).

For example, why do I write:

```
from pylearn2.utils import serial
```

instead of

```
from pylearn2/utils import serial
```

???

Comment: Not all OSs use `/` as the path separator, plus, as the answer states, that's how attributes are accessed, so if a subpackage is an attribute of a package (which it sometimes is), that's how it would be written in code.

Answer (score 4):

Because Python sees packages and modules as **objects**, and thus uses dot-notation to access their "attributes".

More on package objects and their notation:

- **From Guido, himself – http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/pytut/Packages.html**
- **From the Python docs –  https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html**

And here's some proof in importing the [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/download/) package:

```
>>> import django
>>> type(django)
<type 'module'>
>>> type(django.contrib.auth.models)
<type 'module'>
```

Comment: Intuitively this seems correct, but a citation or something explaining that that's the reason for `import`'s syntax being the way it is would be nice.

Comment: @IsmailBadawi Agreed. I apologize for the initial brevity; I was using the mobile app, and it was difficult to write the answer out. I've edited my post with citations and examples.

Comment: @IsmailBadawi - slash notation wouldn't work in other places. Suppose I tried to use `os/path/join('a', 'b')`, python would think I'm doing division.

Comment: @tdelaney In this hypothetical case, the `module` class could override the `/` operator for submodule access. (Not that I'm advocating for the use of anything other than dot-notation)

Answer (score 2):

A vast majority of programming languages use dots/periods for namespace references. The only one that I personally know that doesn't is PHP.

VB:

```
Imports System.Text
Imports System.IO
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.ControlChars
```

C#:

```
using System;
using System.Web.Services.Description;
using System.Collections;
using System.Xml;
```

Java:

```
import javax.swing.*;
```

ActionScript 3:

```
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.Shape;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.filters.DropShadowFilter;
```

PHP:

```
use PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPConnection;
use PhpAmqpLib\Message\AMQPMessage;
```

Comment: Ruby uses '::' (and '/' as the filename separator for require statements):  require 'mymodule/submodule' ; include Mymodule::Submodule

Answer (score 1):

In addition to other answers...

Not all modules are in the file system in the way they are defined on import. That somepackage.somemodule happens to be on the disk at somepackage/somemodule.py is only one way to do it. A C extention, for instance, may be sitting in a different place or with a different name. Also, some modules like to play with their namespaces. 'os.path' may really be 'ntpath' or 'posixpath'.